# Влияние названий url страниц на поисковую оптимизацию и продвижение

Tags: seo, продвижение, оптимизация

Всем привет! Вот почти закончил сайт и задумался. У меня все страницы со статьями и новостями имеют урл типа /news/?id=123. Получается, такой урл не будет участвовать в поиске? Хотелось бы получить ответ на вопрос, **насколько важно** (или обязательно) прописывать урл в виде "/news/название-новости" для индексации страниц и прочих seo-технологий.

P.S. В title у меня все-таки прописываются заголовки статей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще желательно делать ЧПУ (человеко-понятноый урл). Даже [гугл так рекомендует](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329?hl=ru)

Comment: Желательно - это желательно. Было бы интересно услышать: ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО или НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО?

Чутье подсказывает, что надо переделать движок сайта на ЧПУ без id и символов "?"

Comment: Я уже так переделала. На поисковую оптимизацию очень влияет, да и выделяя совпадения жирным, определенно, привлекает внимание пользователей. Соответственно, если даже в ссылке есть совпадения с поисковым запросом, доверия к ресурсу больше.

Comment: @Deus для продвижения в поисковиках - обязательно!

Comment: Вот так бы и сразу!